# Trying to Set Up a Cydia Repo With Amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cydia, repo

I have been recently been trying to set up a cydia repository using Amazon AWS S3 service. I have uploaded the required files to get this to work and yet it still does not. My file structure is

```
Release
Packages.gz
Packages
mydeb.deb
```

These files are all in the same folder and the Packages.gz is linked correctly.

When I try to add the repository to Cydia I get a HTTP 404 error saying it could not find Packages.gz. Any comments?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and found a workaround.

Sync all files to `s3://[your_bucket]/./`

AmazonS3 is a simple KVS(Key-Value Store). Maybe Cydia requests `http://[repo-url]/./Packages.gz`, but S3 can't resolve `/./`.